# Upload asset via API - Asset saved under root folder

Tags: plugin-development, assets-field

I am trying to seed some images to an existing volume programmatically.
The code I'm using is taken (almost) verbatim from Craft's `AssetsController@actionUpload`:

```php
        $filename = Assets::prepareAssetName($filename);

        $asset = new Asset();
        $asset->tempFilePath = $path;
        $asset->filename = $filename;
        $asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
        $asset->setVolumeId($folder->volumeId);
        $asset->uploaderId = User::findOne()->id;
        $asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
        $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
        $res = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);
```

However, this creates a new folder on the root of my project, by the same name as the one that already exists under `web`, and saves the file there, which results in a broken asset in the CP.

When I upload using Craft's CP the file is uploaded correctly to `web/{volumeFolder}`.

I have dumped the `$asset` object both from my plugin code and from Craft's code and compared them. Everything matches (`volumeId`, `folderId`, `tempFilePath`).

I couldn't track the place in the code where the folder is created. I'd appreciate some pointers.

EDIT:

To answer @MoritzLost comment here is the full context:

```php
private function generateImages()
    {
        $assetVolume = Craft::$app->volumes->getVolumeByHandle(Handles::ASSETS);
        $assets = Asset::find()->volume($assetVolume)->all();

        // Generate new assets
        if (count($assets) === 0) {
            // Find folder
            $folder = VolumeFolder::findOne([
                'volumeId' => $assetVolume->id
            ]);

            // images in plugin folder
            $dir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../assets/site/images');
            $images = ['hero_1', 'img_1', 'img_2', 'img_3', 'img_4'];

            // temp folder in project
            $path = new Path();
            $tempDirPath = $path->getTempPath();

            foreach ($images as $image) {
                // move file from plugin assets to project temp folder
                $filename = $image . '.jpg';
                $filenameUnique = $image . '_' . rand(100, 10000) . '.jpg';
                $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
                $tempFilePath = $tempDirPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filenameUnique;
                file_put_contents($tempFilePath, file_get_contents($path));


                // Upload asset to permanent folder
                // and create DB record
                $result = $this->uploadNewAsset($folder, $tempFilePath, $filenameUnique);

                $assets[] = $result;
            }
        }

        return array_map(function ($asset) {
            return $asset->id;
        }, $assets);

    }
```

```php
 private function uploadNewAsset($folder, string $path, $filename)
    {
        $filename = Assets::prepareAssetName($filename);

        $asset = new Asset();
        $asset->tempFilePath = $path;
        $asset->filename = $filename;
        $asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
        $asset->setVolumeId($folder->volumeId);
        $asset->uploaderId = User::findOne()->id;
        $asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
        $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);
        $res = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);

        if (!$res) {
            blogify_log("Failed to save image");
        }

        return $asset;
    }
```

Checked `folderId` and it matches. `tempFilePath` is `{projectRoot}/storage/runtime/temp/{filename}`, which also matches Craft CP request.

Comment: How are you defining the `$path` and `$folder` variables? The error might be with those.

Comment: @MoritzLost Added full context to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure yet what caused the issue, but it is probably somehow related to the fact that I also created the volume programmatically.
At any rate, using an absolute path during volume creation solved the issue:

```php
$volumesService->createVolume([
            'type' => Local::class,
            'name' => 'Assets Volume',
            'handle' => 'assetsVolumeHandle',
            'hasUrls' => 1,
            'url' => '/assets-url',
            'settings' => [
                'path' => 'assetsFolder'
            ]
        ]);
```

Replace `assetsFolder` with `@webroot/assetsFolder` (and while you're at it replace `/assets-url` with `@web/assets-url`).